# Linux command to find the which are the jars loaded by the jvm

Tags: java, linux

Can someone let me know, what will be unix command if I need to check want are the jars loaded by java..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use lsof:

```
lsof -p <PID> | grep jar
```

use pgrep or jps to find the PID of your Java process.

Comment: @Omry: +1 for the OP specifically mentioning Un*x and your answer being an answer that *"thinks outside the Java box"*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option: `java -verbose:class` which shows what jars are being used

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to go about this.

From your java code you can call `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` which will return the whole classpath as a String.

You can also get the list by adding an argument on the command line `java -verbose:class`